# How can I run .launch files from launch file?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi !
i have to run two launch file before run rviz  in launch code. i wrote this code :

```
<param name="rbx2_bringup" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find rbx2_bringup)/launch/pi_robot_with_gripper.launch'" />  
<param name="pi_robot_moveit_config" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find pi_robot_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch'" />  
 <!-- Show in Rviz   -->
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find rbx2_arm_nav)/config/arm_paths.rviz"/>
```

please edit code for me and write correct code.
thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247336/how-can-i-run-.launch-files-from-launch-file-?/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> please edit code for me and write correct code. thank you !

I will not write your code for you. We're here to offer free advice; if you want someone to build your software for you, they'll probably want to get paid for their time.

That said, you probably want the `<include>` tag in roslaunch: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include

You may also want to read the [roslaunch tips for large projects tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects), because it discusses a lot of the different ways that you can use roslaunch to include other launch files, set parameters and run nodes.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2016-11-06**:
thanks that was very helpful.